# Creating Windows .exe from a Linux Python package

Tags: python, linux, windows, pyinstaller, executable

I have an extensive Python package which I have written under Linux Mint 20. I created a Linux executable, packaging all in a single file for potentially distributing it, with PyInstaller.

Now I would like to do a similar thing but for distribution to Windows users. Since I have no easy access to a Windows machine, is there a way I can do that from within the Linux environment?

**EDIT**  - To clarify my question, I would like to use my existing code *without changing it*. So importing my code in a Windows environment and adjusting it, to then create an executable, is not really feasible for me since I do not know the Windows programming environment nor do I have reliable access to a Windows machine. I would like to create an executable *within Linux Mint* that could work *in a Windows system*.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! As far as I know - no, you need a Windows machine to create a Windows PyInstaller package.

Comment: @David Thank you. Are there other tools other than PyInstaller that might do the job?

Comment: in case you haven't found out yet, you can do it with pyinstaller under wine.
There are pretty good instructions here:
https://www.makeworld.space/2021/10/linux-wine-pyinstaller.html